# Random variable probabilities with a weighted coin

Tags: probability, random-variables

Suppose a coin is tossed $n$ times, with a random variable $X = X_H - X_T$ denoting the difference between the number of heads and number of tails.

I know that $X$ can take on every other integer value between $-n$ and $n$. Now, I am interested in probabilities. Say, $n=5$ and the probability of getting a heads is $2/3$. I want to find the associated probabilities that $X$ can assume. I am wondering if I am doing this correctly: let's say $X = 1$. This means that there were 3 heads and 2 tails. Then $P(X) = {5 \choose 3}(\frac{2}{3})^3 \times {5 \choose 2} (\frac{1}{3})^2$. Alternatively, let's say $X=3$. Then $P(X) = {5 \choose 4}(\frac{2}{3})^4 \times {5 \choose 1} (\frac{1}{3})$. Or if X=5, then $P(X) = (\frac{2}{3})^5$. Am I calculating these probabilities correctly, or are some of these wrong?

Lastly, for general $n$ and general probability of heads $p$, I am interested in the general probability for each value of that $X$ can take. I am unsure of how to do this.

Comment: You are not calculating correctly.  In the case of $3$ heads for example, you should have ${5\choose3}\left(\frac23\right)^3\left(\frac13\right)^2$  You should not multiply by ${5\choose2}$ because once the $3$ tosses that will come up heads are chosen, the $2$ tosses that will come up tails are determined.  There are no more choices to make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the are $n$ coin tosses with probability of having head to be $p$. First, note that the probability of $X = k$ is zero if $n+k$ is an odd number. Now, assume $n+k$ is even. The event $X = k$ means that there are $(n+k)/2$ heads and $(n-k)/2$ tails (note that $k$ can be negative). Following the comment of @saulspatz the probability can be written as
$$Pr(X=k) = {n \choose (n+k)/2} p^{(n+k)/2} (1-p)^{(n-k)/2}.$$